# android:installLocation="preferExternal" and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: java, android, permissions

If I declare in my manifest

`android:installLocation="preferExternal"` ,

do I also need to declare

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does "preferExternal" work to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only looking to install there, then no. If you need to store additional data and you want to write to /sdcard/, then you do need the second declaration.

As an addition, if you call `getExternalFilesDir(String)` or `getExternalCacheDir()` (which exist on the /sdcard/), you also do NOT need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Only if you want to use a custom location.